# when to use cc.textureCache in cocos2d-js?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

```
    //code 1:
        var texTransparent = cc.textureCache.addImage(res.textureTransparentPack_png);
        this.spriteSheet = cc.SpriteBatchNode.create(texTransparent);

     //code:2
        this.spriteSheet = cc.SpriteBatchNode.create(res.textureTransparentPack_png);
```

both the statements are working well, i don't know when to use textureCache and when not ?

Comment: I wouldn't use SpriteBatchNode anymore, as it is depricated in cocos2d-x. The functionality of it is also "under the hood".

Comment: so what should i use instead of it, is there any replacement in of it in cocos2d-js  ?

Comment: You don't have to use a replacement. The caching is done by cocos2d now. I just use   cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.any_plist);
to load a sprite sheet and then       var spriteFrame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(any_image),
       sprite = cc.Sprite.create(spriteFrame,cc.rect(0,0,width,height));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both variants should be OK, as the second one will search texture cache too. For the sake of simplicity, personally I'd use the second one. Regarding the question, don't use texture cache if you're not sure. Cocos will cache textures for you under the hood.